GET Host and Cluster from VM using VMware REST API
Is it possible to get host name and cluster name of each VM running on VMware ESXi version 7?
Ex. In vCenter, I have
Cluster : My Cluster
Host in My Cluster : esx1.my.lab, esx2.my.lab, esx3.my.lab
And there're many VM running on those 3 hosts.
I want to automate using REST API to GET name of every VM, Host which that VM located and Cluster of that Host.
Now I can get the List of VM and VM name by using
https://{api_host}/api/vcenter/vm
Then use each vm_id to loop and get vm name by using
https://{api_host}/api/vcenter/vm/{vm_id}
But I can't find how to get host and cluster information from each VM.
